# Need help in changing the background color of "flair"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design, blogger

I am trying to include the "flair" in my website. One problem I face is that I cannot change the background color. I went to the flair page and saw that I should use the css style to change. I am very poor in CSS. I have my domain in blogger. So it would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to do it.

This is what I've done which is not working

```
<script style="background-color:grey" 
  src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/252398.js?theme=clean" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Comment: @Jon: Yeah I tried it. I used the theme "clean" but I cannot change the background color

Comment: Scroll down the page, it shows how to customize the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing wrong with this. :)

Styles go *inside* style tags, like so:

```
<style>
    .valuable-flair { background-color: gray !important; }
</style>
```

Make sure that goes in between the `<head>` tags. `!important` makes sure that style overrides the one specified in the Javascript. You should put that *under* this revised line:

```
<script src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/252398.js?theme=clean" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And you should be fine.

You can only apply styles like that to tags *inside* the `<body>` tag, although that's bad practice. One better would be to put it between `<style>` tags, the other would be to put  it all in a separate stylesheet and link to it using a `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag.

Comment: http://www.technicalypto.com/ If you see the page, the box is kind of cut in the bottom. Any idea why ?

Comment: The CSS is restricting .valuable-flair's height to `50px`. To that `.valuable-flair` rule, make sure to add `height: auto !important;` again, to make sure it overrides the Javascript's version. 

(Just a note that !important should be used sparingly, we're just using it a lot here because we're importing a CSS file via JS.)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your page. Css is not an attribute for the script tag.

```
<style>
.valuable-flair
{
        background-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/YOURUSERID.js
will produce the flair, which you can customize with CSS.